# How can I deserialize an object containing a DataTable with enum values using DataContractSerializer?

Tags: c#, enums, datatable, datacontractserializer

Say I have this simple class in a module called `ClassLibrary1`:

```
[DataContract]
public class Class1
{
    [DataMember]
    private DataTable _data;

    public void SetData(string key, object value)
    {
        _data = new DataTable("SomeName");
        _data.Columns.Add("Key", typeof(String));   
        _data.Columns.Add("Value", value.GetType());
        _data.Rows.Add(key, value);
    }
}
```

and in a separate module called `ClassLibrary2`, I have the following class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Configuration
{
    [DataMember]
    private Class1 _obj;

    public Configuration()
    {
        _obj = new Class1();
        _obj.SetData("Key", MyEnum.Value2);
    }
}
```

Additionally, the module `ClassLibrary2` defines an enum called `MyEnum`, which is not marked as public, i.e. it is internal to the module (and used in the code above, as you can see).

Now, in my main module, I do not want to depend on `ClassLibrary2`, but rather I need to load it dynamically at runtime. That is, I use `Assembly.LoadFrom`, then find the type I need to use (in my simple example I just search for the type named "Configuration"), and create an instance using `Activator.CreateInstance`. Then I serialize the instance like this:

```
var ser = new DataContractSerializer(config.GetType());
var outstream = new FileStream("c:\\test.xml", FileMode.Create);
ser.WriteObject(outstream, config);
outstream.Close();
```

So far everything works find. But when I try to deserialize it like this:

```
var instream = new FileStream("c:\\test.xml", FileMode.Open);
var conf = ser.ReadObject(instream);
```

I get an `ArgumentException`, with the message "Column requires a valid DataType." I have found out that this does not occur if I either

- Define MyEnum in the main module instead
- Replace the DataTable with a simple `String key; Object value`
- Use something else instead of the enum MyEnum (e.g. a string)

But none of these options are very desirable in my real application. The first option would create a strong coupling between modules that should not be dependent upon each other. The second option is possible, but a bit much work (I already use the DataTable many places throughout the class, and only recently found that I had to do serialization), and the third option is sort of messy, too.

Are there any other ways I can get this to work? I've also tried adding the MyEnum to the serializer's list of known types, both through the `DataContractSerializer` constructor and by appending `[KnownType(typeof(MyEnum))]` in front of the `Configuration` class declaration, but this did not help.

Comment: can you post your Enum declaration?

Comment: Sure: enum MyEnum { Value1, Value2, Value3 }

Comment: did you try to mark your enum as a `[DataContract]` and each member as `[EnumMemberAttribute]`?

Comment: Tried that, but got the exact same error.

Comment: just tried it on mine, it doesn't throw any errors.

Comment: look at the [screenie](http://i44.tinypic.com/2wq6eir.png)

Comment: Yeah, but in your code, you have all the classes in the same namespace, right? In my project, I have to keep them in seperate projects, with no dependencies between them. That's why I use Activator.CreateInstance etc.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying code just can't find the ClassLibrary2 assembly full name that's been written down in the test.xml file automatically. It needs some help.

You can workaround this if you hook the [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) prior deserialization, something like this:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomainAssemblyResolve;
...
var instream = new FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Open);
var conf = ser.ReadObject(instream);
...

private static Assembly CurrentDomainAssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Name == "ClassLibrary2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null") // adapt to your needs of course
        return Assembly.LoadFrom(@"mypath\ClassLibrary2.dll");

    return null; // don't know for this one
}
```

Comment: OK, that worked, but I don't understand why. I already have `Assembly.LoadFrom(@"c:\ClassLibrary2.dll");` at the very start of my program. So why would I need to tell the system to load this file again?

Comment: It doesn't work as is because underlying serialization code calls something like Type.GetType("ClassLibrary2.MyEnum, ClassLibrary2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null") (an assembly qualified type name) but that can only work if ClassLibrary2 can be resolved automatically (for example, if it's in the .EXE path). If you copy ClassLibrary2.dll in the path, it will also work. More here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/30/using-type-gettype-typename.aspx